# If Else in python not working with user input

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

```
print ("Hello, this is the bullcrap lottery!!")
name = input("What is your name?")
if 'Jackson' or 'jackson' in name:
    print ("Hello %s! You are a special guest from the Jackson Family!" % name)
else:
    print ("Hello boring %s" % name)
```

Comment: Please format your code and provide a sample input, along with expected and actual results.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what is giving you difficulty. Are you getting an error? If so, please show the error message. If you are getting behaviour that does not match your expectation, please provide the input, expected output and actual output please.

Comment: FWIW - Your condition should probably be `if name in ('Jackson', 'jackson')`. Or simply: `if name.lower() == 'jackson'`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (name=='Jackson'||name='jackson'):
    print ("Hello %s! You are a special guest from the Jackson Family!" % name)
else:
    print ("Hello boring %s" % name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its python3 code version.

Run it: `python3 yourfile.py`